# Bootstrap and JS - How to fit high number in a limited <div> space

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, numbers

Am trying to display a number in a cell, this number can vary from very small to gigantic such as 3.3078854415193856e+107 for instance. But as you can see below they are going outside of the limit of the cell.

This is the code where the number is going to:

```
>   <div class="col-sm-6 my-col" align="center">
>        <text class="my-text-topdashboard-value"> id="id-topdashbaord-value2">5040</text>
>   </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to automatically fix the size of the number so it never gets higher than a pre-defined number of characters or that the current space available in the flex column? aka when the number becomes too big, it will automatically add e+xx at the end.

For instance (with also comma thousands separators...)

- 5,040
- 40,320
- 479,001,600
- 8.68331176e+36
- 9.23564546e+107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the javascript method toPrecision() 
(ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision) 
on all your values:

```
(100000000000).toPrecision(3)
```

returns the string: "1.00e+11"

```
(1000000).toPrecision(3)
```

returns: "1.00e+6"

and

```
(5040).toPrecision(3)
```

returns: "5.04e+3"

etc..

where the value passed: 3, is the precision you want - you can play around with this to get a value that suits you best.

then most of your numbers will be drawn with less variation in length.

Comment: Thank you, will play with it indeed and potentially activate it only for number above a pre-define threshold...so I can keep lower number as full ones.